# Make a ping in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to ping a page with my react native app, to test if a URL is reachable or not.

I tried to use ping-litle but I have an error message an i can't find a solution

```
UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module react-native-ping-litle from /Users/tetar/Desktop/myombox_react/MY_OM_BOX/index.ios.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/tetar/Desktop/myombox_react/MY_OM_BOX/node_modules
,   /Users/tetar/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

actually i did this

```
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
 if (request.readyState !== 4) {
  return;
 }

 if (request.status === 200) {
console.log('success'); // just print a success on console 
} else {
 console.log('error'); // just print a error on console
}
};

request.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.254/'); //put your adresse here 
request.send();
```

I don't know if it's the best way but it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a good idea but you can set a time out for your fetch requests.

```js
function checkStatus(url, timeout, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    fetch(url)
    .then((data)=>{ resolve(data) })
    .catch((e)=>{ reject(e) })
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
      callback()
      reject(throw new Error('Timeout'))
    },timeout)
  })
}
```

so you send a timeout value (10, 15 sec, etc), a url and a callback.

Hope it helps